# No Exception is thrown when a serializable class is serialized with a Non-serializable reference field value is null

Tags: java, serialization

Class A implements serializable and has a reference to class B.
B is not implementing serializable. class A has reference to B as null when it is getting serialized. But no exception is thrown, why is this?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 2):

Because it only counts if the actual objects encountered during serialization are `Serializable`.

For instance `A.b` could also reference an object of a subclass of `B` which implements `Serializable`.